# Best way to implement expensive derived properties in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a somewhat complicated situation. I'm implementing a simple scrolling chat view in SwiftUI. There's a `ChatView` with a list of `ChatMessageCell`s. Each `Message` has a `User`, and that has a `ProfileImage` which is a struct made up of a couple of fields (`bucket` and `key`, used to construct the URL to the image on the server). This can periodically update on the `User` class, and can also be `nil`.

**Update:** This is not a particularly expensive operation, but let’s say for the sake of argument that it is expensive, and I only want to recompute it once. There basically two ways: recompute when (one of the) source properties changes, or recompute when needed and store the result. I’d like to know the best way to do both.

The view needs to construct the URL, because it needs to specify the desired image size for the image. In this way, the URL is a derived property of the `message.user.profileImage` property.

I tried using `.onChange(of: self.message.user.profileImage)` in my `ChatMessageCell` view hierarchy to then compute the URL and set `self.profileImageURL`, but you can’t set simple properties. So I adorned `self.profileImageURL` with `@State`, which allowed the code to compile, and I assign it in `init()`. But if it’s `@State`, that assignment doesn't seem to have any effect.

So, I'm pretty unsure how to do this.

`ChatView` and `ChatMessageCell` look like this:

```swift
struct ChatView : View
{
    @ObservedObject public  var     stream          :   ChatStream
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(self.stream.messages) { inMsg in
                        ChatMessageCell(message: inMsg)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct
ChatMessageCell: View
{
    public  let     message                 :   ChatStream.Message
    @State  var     profileImageURL         :   URL?
    
    init(message inMessage: ChatStream.Message)
    {
        self.message = inMessage
        let image = inMessage.user.profileImage
        let url = image?.sharpImageURL(forSize: kProfileImageSize)
        self.profileImageURL = url              //  <-- doesn't assign if @State
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading)
        {
            Text("Key: \(self.message.user.profileImage?.key ?? "nil")")
            Text("URL: \(self.profileImageURL?.absoluteString ?? "nil")")
            //  This is just for debugging. Really there's a `KFImage` here that’s
            //  supposed to async load the image.
        }
        .onChange(of: self.message.user.profileImage)
            { inVal in
                let url = inVal?.sharpImageURL(forSize: kProfileImageSize)
                self.profileImageURL = url      //  <-- can't modify if not @State
            }
    }
}
```

Other classes:

```swift
class ChatStream
{
    public struct Message
    {
        var id              :   Int
        var date            :   Date
        var message         :   String
        var user            :   User
        
        init(fromIncoming inMsg: IncomingMessage, user inUser: User)
        {
            self.id = inMsg.id
            self.date = inMsg.date
            self.message = inMsg.message
            self.user = inUser
        }
    }
    
    public class User
    {
        typealias ID = String
        
                    let id                  :   ID
                    var username            :   String
                    var onlineAt            :   Date?
        @Published  var profileImage        :   ProfileImage?
        
        init(fromIncoming inUser: IncomingUser)
        {
            self.id = inUser.id
            self.username = inUser.username
            self.onlineAt = inUser.onlineAt
            self.profileImage = inUser.profileImage
        }
        
        func update(fromIncoming inUser: IncomingUser)
        {
            self.username = inUser.username
            self.onlineAt = inUser.onlineAt
            self.profileImage = inUser.profileImage
        }
    }
    
    @Published  var         messages                                                =   OrderedSet<Message>()
    @Published  var         users                                                   =   [User.ID : User]()
}   

extension ChatStream : ObservableObject {}
extension ChatStream.ProfileImage : Equatable {}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be more straightforward to have `message` be an observable object, which triggers changes when the user property updates, and have the URL be a computed property of `message`. You haven't shown the implementation of `Message` or `User` so it's hard to be specific. If `Message` is a struct then you could just have a reference to the user as an observable object.

Comment: I edited the question to add the other classes.

Comment: Welp, I feel like an idiot. Computed property certainly seems to work. However, is there a way to compute it once (when `profileImage` changes), rather than every time a new cell is created?

Comment: `User` could have a dictionary of cached URLs, keyed on size, which it clears out when profileImage changes. It could then lazily supply size-specific URLs on demand but only have to compute once.